# How do I stop a runaway setInterval() timer in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

setInterval hangs when I hold the left mouse button down and sequentially press the right button. setInterval will not clear after that.

```
    var timer = 0;

    document.getElementById('c_3').onmousedown = function(e) {

          timer = setInterval(function() {myFunction();}, 30);

          if (e.which == 2 || e.which == 3) {

                clearInterval(timer);

          }

    }
```

Comment: The interval identified by `timer` can be cancelled immediately after it's created (if `e.which` has a suitable value) or it will never be cancelled, because future clicks will spawn a brand new interval in addition to the existing interval, and overwite the old `timer` value. Should you put a `if(e.which == 1)` condition?

Comment: Did you mean to clear the previous interval, not the interval that just started?

Comment: Also! Before it's too late, get into the habit of using `let` instead of `var`

Comment: Will try an If(e.which == 1) , thank you.

Comment: Hi apsillers, it worked, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it works now ...

```
    let timer = 0;

    document.getElementById('c_3').onmousedown = function(e) {

      if (e.which == 1) {

        timer = setInterval(function() {myFunction();}, 30);

      }

      if (e.which == 2 || e.which == 3) {

        document.getElementById('c_3').oncontextmenu = function() {

          return false;

        }

        clearInterval(timer);

      }

    }

    document.getElementById('c_3').onmouseup = function() {

        clearInterval(timer);

    }
```